# Deriving an expression for the spacing of bumps on the road given that the car suspension is resonating

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

> The suspension of a car may be considered to be an ideal spring under compression. When the driver, of mass $m_1$, steps into the car, of mass $m_2$, the vertical height of the car above the road decreases by $x$. If the car is driven over a series of equally spaced bumps, the amplitude of vibration becomes much larger at one particular speed. Explain why this occurs and find an expression for the separation $d$ of the bumps if it occurs at a speed of $v$.

This is clearly because of resonance, so assuming that the distribution of bumps on the road is sinusoidal, the frequency of the 'bump' wave (the driving frequency) must be the same as the natural frequency for there to be maximum resonance.

For a mass-ideal spring system the (natural) period of simple harmonic oscillation is given by:

$$T = 2 \pi \sqrt {\frac {m}{k}}$$

Where $k$ is the spring constant, $m$ is the load mass on the spring and $T$ is the period. The derivation of this would drag this question on but it is definitely true.

For the 'bump wave':

$$\lambda = \frac {c}{f}$$

$$d = \frac{v}{f} = v \ T$$

By substituting in the value for $T$:

$$d = 2 \pi \ v \sqrt {\frac {m}{k}}$$

$m$ in this case is actually $m_1 + m_2$, since this is the load mass on the spring. Also, $k = F/x$, and $F = (m_1 + m_2) \ g$, so:

$$\frac{m_1 + m_2}{k} = \frac{x}{g}$$

Therefore:

$$d = 2 \pi \ v \sqrt {\frac {x}{g}}$$

This is the answer I submitted, but I got it wrong, and the only help given was this: https://youtu.be/zZtJM8zfp5o.

Have I made a conceptual error, or is this still a valid answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made an error with your masses. *x* is the extra spring compression due to the driver of mass $m_1$ getting into the car, so $$m_1g=kx.$$ This gives you the $k$ to put in the mass-spring formula. The relevant *mass* for the car-with-driver oscillating is $(m_1+m_2)$.

the rest is up to you!